# Interact with another program with C#

Tags: c#, windows, automation

I wish to interact with other Windows applications from my C# application. This should be able to be done in the background, while a user continues doing something else. The target applications are not mine, but I do know what they are, so their UI/etc. is known.

I am basically trying to automate the process of various tasks across a variety of programs.

So far, the only solution I can think of, is having the code switch to the relevant window, and carry out the task with the mouse. ([Controlling the mouse with methods as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620345/c-sharp-clicking-on-a-certain-point-on-the-screen))

The downfall of this approach of course, is it cannot run in the background and stops the user from carrying out other tasks.

Of course if these target applications received 'fake' mouse clicks, while still running in the background, this solution would be great. So if that's possible, please do share! Otherwise, any solution for such a problem would be brilliant.

Comment: Have you tried to find any APIs linked with accessing other programs in windows?

Comment: I know of none, I guessed they were out there but could find none, so if you could point me in the direction of one that would be great.

Comment: Does the program expose any API in which is specifically allows itself to be programmatically manipulated?  There really isn't anything in the general case for this, it's more of a program by program process.

Comment: Some do Servy, and I have covered those applications. Others don't so this directly targets the other ones. Others still have API's that let you replicate the programs functionality within your own application, however that is not what I am after, I would still like the user to be able to switch window to see the process being carried out (if it a process you can see the visual changes of). -- Short answer, no.

Comment: Try `System.Windows.Automation`. It uses the accessibility interfaces to control applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just want to say that what you are doing is going to be pretty tough to make reliable without cooperation from the developers of the other applications.  However, you can use Windows Messages to accomplish what you're trying to do.  This is a way to send information to a window without explicit communications being set up.  You'll need to use native methods to do this, but it's pretty straightforward.  Be careful, however, as implementing this is not as trivial as it looks - you can get into deadlocks if you accidentally send a message to a closed (or invisible) window, for example.

This is too big a topic for a Stack Overflow post, but here are some relevant functions to get you started:

[PostMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) are the main functions you can use to send messages to other applications.

The answers to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407769/directly-sending-keystrokes-to-another-process-via-hooking) have some basic examples of how to use these functions.

Finally, [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/SendMessageList.htm) is a list of Windows message codes for reference.